# Cordova Hammer.js - Multiple "press" events

Tags: javascript, cordova, events, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js "press" event, and it works fine. The problem I have is when I want to press a different location with my left thumb while holding down pressed with my right thumb. Apparently I have to lift up thumb before performing any other touches. How do I do multiple presses without lifting?

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

var mc = new Hammer(myElement,
{
    hold: false,
    release: false
});

mc.add(new Hammer.Press({
    event: 'press',
    pointer: 1,
    threshold: 30,
    time: 1
}));
mc.on("press", function(event)
{
    //This works, but only single touch, until touch is lifted
    //can I do second.
    x1 = event.center.x;
    y1 = event.center.y;

    //This doesn't -> Trying new things
    x2 = event.touches[1].x;
    y2 = event.touches[1].y;        
});
```

And I'm curently trying this, which doesn't work at all.

```
mc.on("touch", function(event)
{
    x1 = event.touches[0].pageX;
    y1 = event.touches[0].pageY;
    x2 = event.touches[1].pageX;
    y2 = event.touches[1].pageY;
    //OR
    x1 = event.gesture.touches[0].pageX;
    y1 = event.gesture.touches[0].pageY;
    x2 = event.gesture.touches[1].pageX;
    y2 = event.gesture.touches[1].pageY;
});
```

Comment: Please write code what have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have further edited question.